# error BUILD FAILURE in creating maven project

Tags: java, maven

I want to create a project by execute this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DgroupId=org.geoserver -DartifactId=hello -Dversion=1.0 -DinteractiveMode=false
```

and this error is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.122s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 26 18:00:21 IRDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/75M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\Iman). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException`
```

what can i do?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question :P

Comment: Fix the title of your question, as you are not asking anything in particular.

Comment: I ran the exact same command and it worked perfectly for me. What version of Maven are you using? `mvn --version`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the command

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId="Name of group ID" -DgroupId="group id here" -DartifactId="put artifact id here"
```

It should work. I've never seen the -DinteractiveMode command before and it will generally ask you for a version number in the set up.